# Missing "move to screen" in KDE

Tags: kde, kde5

I clearly remember that in window menu (after right clicking in task bar) there is sometimes action named like "Move to screen" (I don't mean "Move to desktop"). How to set it so it is always available? (I have connected 2 monitors all times.)

Answer (score 1):

Now you can, there are several shortcuts you can assign in the global keyboard short-cut panel.
"Window to X Screen" just assign the key you need.

I had the same problem, i just found the solution from an idea on another anwser.4

[image: shortcut to move to another screen]